# Retrieving all values from an array in AutoHotkey script

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I have created an array as `xArray:=[2, 3, 4]`

I need to use these values one by one in a loop.

I have tried using a counter variable, but it didn't work.

There's even a predefined "A_Index" variable in ahk scripts. Can someone elaborate on that? It might be the solution.

Comment: I don't know AHK, but searching in the docs I found the snippet `Loop %ArrayCount% { element := Array%A_Index% }`, (where ArrayCount is the size of the array) which seems to do an array traversal. Source: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm

Comment: but then i want to access the value of each element.. this would just help me to get the Count..

Comment: The variable `element` seems to receive the value in the given position, similar to `element = Array[i];` in C.

Comment: @Mephy They way you've described is the "old" array notation using sequentially numbered variables as pseudo arrays. AHK_L on the other hand provides support for actual arrays, similar to JavaScript's syntax and usage. For direct comparison, please read [AHK_L arrays](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays).

Answer (score 4):

```
xArray:=[2, 3, 4] 
for key, val in xArray
    MsgBox % val
```

Comment: Is it possible to use array values and regular text in a single MsgBox?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro `MsgBox % "this is a regular text " val " some more text"`